# node.js change in concatenation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchbase

I'm trying to debug some code that another programmer has left for me to maintain. I've just attempted to upgrade from node.js 5 to node.js 8 and my database queries are for *some* requests coming back with key not found errors

We're using couchbase for the database and our document keys are "encrypted" for security. So we may have a key that starts like this "User_myemail@gmail.com" but we encrypt it using the following method:

```
function _GetScrambledKey(dbKey)
{
    //select encryption key based on db key content
    var eKeyIndex = CalculateEncryptionKeyIndex(dbKey, eKeys.length);
    var sha = CalculateSHA512(dbKey + eKeyIndex);
    return sha;
}

function CalculateEncryptionKeyIndex(str, max)
{
    var hashBuf = CalculateSHA1(str);
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < hashBuf.length; i++)
    {
        count += hashBuf[i];
        count = count % max;
    }
    return count;
}
```

We then query couchbase for the document with

```
cb.get("ECB_"+encryptedKey, opts, callback);
```

In node5 this worked but in node8 we're getting some documents return fine and others return as missing. I outputted the `"ECB_"+encryptedKey` as an int array and the results have only confused me more. They are different on node5 to node8 but only by one character right in the middle of the array.

Outputting the encryptedKey as an int array on both versions shows this

`188,106,14,227,211,70,94,97,63,130,78,246,155,65,6,148,62,215,47,230,211,109,35,99,21,60,178,74,195,13,233,253,187,142,213,213,104,58,168,60,225,148,25,101,155,91,122,77,2,99,102,235,26,71,157,99,6,47,162,152,58,181,21,175`

Then outputting the concatenated string, in the same way, shows slightly different results

This is the node8 output
`Node8 key: 69,67,66,95,65533,106,14,65533,65533,70,94,97,63,65533,78,65533,65533,65,6,65533,62,65533,47,65533,65533,109,35,99,21,60,65533,74,65533,13,65533,65533,65533,65533,65533,65533,104,58,65533,60,65533,25,101,65533,91,122,77,2,99,102,65533,26,71,65533,99,6,47,65533,65533,58,65533,21,65533`

And this is the node5 output
`Node5 key: 69,67,66,95,65533,106,14,65533,65533,70,94,97,63,65533,78,65533,65533,65,6,65533,62,65533,47,65533,65533,109,35,99,21,60,65533,74,65533,13,65533,65533,65533,65533,65533,65533,104,58,65533,60,65533,65533,25,101,65533,91,122,77,2,99,102,65533,26,71,65533,99,6,47,65533,65533,58,65533,21,65533`

I had to run it through a diff tool to see the difference
[image]
Comparing that to the original pre-append array it looks like the 225 has just been dropped in node8. Is 225 significant? I can't understand how that would be possible otherwise unless it's a bug. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `console.log(typeof encryptedKey)` before that line? If it is a string, concat is straightforward. If it is an object then there is a possibility that there are changes.

Comment: I did, yes. It's an object. I also ran JSON.stringify and its the same in 5 and 6 `json: {"type":"Buffer","data":[26,66,54.....]}`
If the concatenation HAS changed then I need to find a way to restore the original functionality

Comment: The composite's object `toString` will probably return just `[object Object]` here. It definitely wouldn't work before. Are you sure the `encryptedKey` was just just an array before but you've made some changes and it's `{type:..., data:...}` now? I bet you had `ECB_26,66,54` but somehow you have an issue after some changes here.

Comment: By the looks of it `encryptedKey` is a Node `Buffer`, which has a `toString` method, so I don't think you'd get `[object Object]`. The example they gave was of the JSONified representation of it, not the actual structure of the object. @RealWorld - I'd recommend checking if `encryptedKey.toString()` returns the same value on both versions.

Comment: Also, if you see the old programmer, give him a slap upside the head for relying on Node's default string representations not changing :p

Comment: I've updated the original post with the latest information I've found. I'm still confused.

Comment: @RealWorld you need to post code we can run, with some sample input /desired output. You put up two functions, then a one line snippet that has no apparent connection that generates the problem. All we can give you is guesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a change in v8 5.5 https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21278

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the issues you are facing, including the concatenation can be cleaned up using newer features from ES6 that are available in node 8.

In general, you should avoid doing string concatenations with the `+` operator and should use string literals instead.  In your case, you should replace the `"ECB_"+encryptedKey` with `` `ECB_${encryptedKey}` ``.

Additionally, if you want to output the contents of the integers values from this concatenated string, then you are better off using `.join`, the spread operator (`...`) and the `Buffer` class from Node as follows:

```
let encKey = `ECB_${encryptedKey}`;
let tmpBuff = Buffer.from(encKey);
let buffArrVals = [...tmpBuff];
console.log(buffArrVals.join(','));
```

Also, if you can help it, you really should avoid using `var` inside of `function` blocks like it exists in your sample code. `var` performs something called variable hoisting and causes the variable to become available outside the scope it was declared, which is seldom intended.  From node 6+ onward the recommendation is to use `let` or `const` for variable declarations to ensure they stay scoped to the block they are declared.